# Change the font color of the results shown in the suggestion widget when typing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change the font color of the text typed in the keyboard shown in the suggestion widget when the autocomplete feature starts to filter the results.

When you are typing, the results in the suggestion widget change the color of the characters that match what has been typed.

What is the name of the property that does that?

In VSC press ctrl+comma to open the settings and search for the property workbench.colorCustumizations.

There's just a few properties regarding the suggestion widget, I tried them all but I couldn't hit the one.

[This is the ss asked by Alex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGKqJ.jpg)

In time: the virtual keyboard is in the ss cuz my laptop's keyboard went *oo.

Ok so in the suggestion box there is the color for the overall text of the results (white), the color of the text been typed in the editor (red) and the color of the text for the highlighted result in the box (green background).

I want to change the font color for the text that was highlighted by the user (ether by the mouse or the keyboard) because it's hard to see the white text in the green background and I don't want to give up my green lemon.

I hope I was able to explain it so you can understand. Thanks.

Comment: `"editorSuggestWidget.highlightForeground": "#ff6a00"`

Comment: It didn't change the color to orange like you suggested. When I type something in the editor and the autocomplete box shows up, it will always show the color of the text I typed in black. For example, if I type "func" in the editor when the suggestion box comes up it shows the suggestion list with all the suggestions regards "func", but the color of the letters "func" that I typed will always be of black color, don't matter the color value that I put for the "editorSuggestWidget.highlightForeground".

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot? Right now I have no idea what you talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only doable with extension: [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css)

```css
.suggest-widget .monaco-list-row.focused {
    color: #ff6a00;
}
```

Comment: I installed the extension, added the `vscode_custom_css.imports` property to my settings, pasted your reply's code snippet to it, enabled CSS and JS, closed VSC and reopened it, an error message popped up and I clicked in the "Don't show this again" button. Now nothing happens when I open VSC. In my user's settings.json, in the `"vscode_custom_css.imports": [
        .suggest-widget .monaco-list-row.focused {
            color: #ff6a00;
        }
    ]` chunk .suggest... is underlined as it has an error. Am I doing it right? How can I make the warning that popped up earlier show up again?

Comment: `"vscode_custom_css.imports"` is an array of file paths to (.css, .js) files. Example for Windows:  `"vscode_custom_css.imports": ["file:///C:\\Users\\al\\.vscode\\errorColor.css"]`

Comment: Now I get it. It worked, i didn't know it was something so hard to accomplish when i posted the question. Thank you a bunch.